# How many client connections can be established simultaneously via the accept() call of a single server socket instance?

Tags: sockets

*How many client connections can be established simultaneously via the accept() call of a single server
socket instance? Can you change this value?*

I have been given this problem on a homework assignment, and I am very confused. accept() pulls a connection request off the listening socket's queue and makes a new socket out of it...so the number of simultaneous connections is unbound by accept() itself.

What confuses me is the follow up question. If the answer is infinity, then wouldn't it be strange to ask if it can be changed? It sounds like the question is in fact talking about listen(), which takes as a parameter the length of the listening queue. But the question did explicitly say accept().

Answer (score 1):

It's a poorly worded question. As presently stated, it has no definite answer, as it depends on the number of free file descriptors available to the process and the operating system at that moment, and also on other imponderables like kernel memory.

However what is being asked for may be the length of the *backlog* queue, which has nothing to do with `accept()` *per se,* but is determined, or rather hinted at, by the `backlog` parameter to `listen()`, which however can be adjusted up or down by the platform without notice, and without any means being available of discovering what value was actually used.

It's also possible that they are expecting the fallacious answer of 65534, on the assumption that each accepted socket needs a new local port. It doesn't.

Comment: That's essentially what I wrote...I mentioned listen(), because that's probably what the professor was asking about. The rest of the homework is filled with badly worded questions as well.